# Is the union of an increasing sequence of topological copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional topological manifold, and let $(U_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an increasing sequence of open sets $U_k \subset M$ such that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $U_k$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it necessarily the case that $\,U\!:=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty U_k\,$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If so, does anyone know any nice reference for this fact (either as a theorem/lemma/etc. or as an exercise)?

Comment: Cannot you write $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ as such a union?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: No. In such a limit, $\pi_k(M) = \lim \pi_k(U_n)$, so $M$ is automatically contractible.

Comment: Because every curve lies entirely within one $U_k$ by compactness, I see.

Comment: Right (and every homotopy between such too). The claim in the OP should be true by the [annulus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem) but I haven't checked the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You could prove it as a corollary of the [annulus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem) (sketch of a sketch: at each stage the closure $\overline U_n$ is an open $n$-ball, and you're attaching an annulus, and the limit of this procedure is $\Bbb R^n$), but this wasn't known in all dimensions until the 80s. An early proof of this theorem was given in 1961 by Morton Brown [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2034881?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents); it appears to use a modification of the above idea and fact, though I have not at all read it in detail. It appears that this was been known slightly earlier as a corollary of Mazur's proof of the topological Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: As stated this proof is false since there's no reason the closure should be a ball (and obvious not an open one). But if the closure of each is contained in the next, and you have a homeomorphism $U_n \to \Bbb R^n$ you can pull back a sufficiently large closed ball in the latter and consider an increasing sequence of those and apply the annulus theorem.